# Can a Wizard Levitate while Immobilized?

Tags: dnd-4e, move-action, immobilized

When a Wizard is **immobilized** can she still use Levitate to move vertically?

> **Levitate**
>   **Move Action**
>   **Effect:** You can move 4 squares vertically and remain there,  hovering
>   above the ground.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

> *Rules Compendium, page 232:*
>
> **Immobilized**
>
> - The creature can't move unless it teleports or is pulled, pushed, or slid.

Comment: This is correct, since levitation is not given via teleport/push/pull/slide.